# the 'this' keyword inside a jquery plugin function within a componentdidmount

Tags: jquery, reactjs

i have an issue when using react and installing jQuery plugin which is multiselect

Here is the problem, the plugin work just fine but there is something wrong.

```
class MultiSelected extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       this.$el = $(this.el)
       this.$el.multiSelect({
          afterInit: () => {
            //THE THIS HERE
            console.log(this)
          },
       })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.$el.multiSelect('destroy')
    }

    render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <select multiple="multiple" ref={el => { this.el = el }} >
             <option value="1">elem 1</option>
             <option value="2">elem 2</option>
             <option value="3">elem 3</option>
             <option value="4">elem 4</option>
           </select>
         </div>
      )
    }
 }
```

Actually i was expecting something else for the console.log inside the function of afterInit which is refering to the plugin not the class component.

What should i actually do to refer the plugin not the class component.

This is the react version code example
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-meadow-tofic?file=/src/App.js:1411-1570

This is the normal jquery version
https://codepen.io/sylvester1991/pen/NWgRNaW

If you open these 2 you can see the different result from the this, im sorry im not sure what to do here in order to get the 'this' results in the codepen, i need it to integrate the search function, but i cant get the correct data out from the 'this'

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "the plugin work just fine but there is something wrong"? I ran your code sandbox and the `this` is that of the `MultiSelected` component. You issue is unclear. Oh wait, you want it to ***not*** be the `this` of the React component.

Comment: Sometimes the console in codepen fails, you will need to open browser log instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **`This context` is not existing in [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):**

Try to use the normal function to get `this context`:

```
afterInit(ms) {
  console.log(this);
},
```

**Here is your full `componentDidMount`**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.$el = $(this.el);
  this.$el.multiSelect({
    selectableHeader:
      "<input type='text' style='box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; height: auto;' class='search-input' id='search1' autocomplete='off' >",
    selectionHeader:
      "<input type='text' style='box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin-bottom: 5px; height: auto;' class='search-input' id='search2' autocomplete='off' >",
    afterInit(ms) {
      console.log(this);
    },
    afterSelect(values) {
      console.log(values[0]);
    },
    afterDeselect(values) {
      console.log(values[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

**Log with arrow function:**
[image]

**Log with normal function:**
[image]

[image: Edit wizardly-hofstadter-15v0o]

---

**I think you already did in your `normal jquery version`?**

Comment: Hi, you are right, however when i use this in project, it gives me error Expected method shorthand. Any idea?

Comment: I updated the answer, there is a `short hand` way to declare normal function too. See if it helps.

Comment: anyway, `Expected method shorthand` is an eslint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand

Comment: Happy for you too!